# Combine multiple cached/tiled layers on a client-side openlayers application?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, geowebcache, cache

I have Geoserver with integrated geowebcache installed.

I have 3 layers: water, sewer, landbase, and each are cached separately.

1. Is it possible to toggle or combine all 3 cached layers into the openlayers application?
2. Is it efficient to combine all three separately like this? Would performance increase?

Comment: I think this would be better re-worded as a single question.  I would have proceeded to do so but I am not quite clear about what you are asking.

Comment: If they are png with transparency they will work normally when you add one over the other, but I would go for GroupLayer

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Check out [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/), which is capable of combining multiple tile sources, among lots of other things. Really cool app.
2. I can't speak authoritatively on efficiency with this approach, but your app is only making one call instead of three. That seems more efficient, right?

You might even find that it's preferable to handle caching with MapProxy instead. For our particular purpose, that's exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to combine the layers and still cache them using GeoWebCache is to use a `LayerGroup` which acts exactly like a layer in OpenLayers but is built up from the 3 layers in GeoServer.

This is only more efficient if your client always wants to see all three layers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it dynamic, as in, you can change which of the three to view client-side? IF so, you can form up a request that combines 1,2 or 3 layers into a single get request, and OpenLayers can handle this, I reckon.

But, do you need to? Try it the simple way first, and then if you are experiencing performance issues, look into combining it.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, it is possible (see code below)
2. Yes, but performance increase might not be worth the complexity in your web-apps code

   var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("TITLE FOR OVERLAY",
                                  "http://geoserverurl.example:8080/geoserver/ows?",
                                  {layers: "WORKSPACE1:LAYER1,WORKSPACE2,LAYER2"});

-- note, I didn't test the code, but I think it will work!